# Are multiple didBeginContact calls called simultaneously?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

Say two contacts happen at the exact same time. Will their `didBeginContact` function calls happen at the exact same time (in different threads I guess) or will one happen after the other?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and find out for yourself?

Comment: @rickster How can I use breakpoints? I'm talking about multiple threads - breakpoints only tell me about the flow of the program in one thread.

Comment: When you hit a breakpoint, the debugger tells you what thread you're in.

Comment: Sprinkle some NSLogs into your code and see what prints out and when.

Answer (score 0):

No - `didBeginContact` is called for every pair of nodes that contact in your scene. The parameter passed to it is an `SKPhysicsContact` which contains references to the 2 bodies - `bodyA` and `bodyB` - involved in the contact.

If 3 nodes (e.g. `player`, `enemy` and `bomb`) appear to contact each other simultaneously, then `didBegincontact` will be called 3 times  - once for the player`/`enemy contact, once for the player`/`bomb contact and once for the enemy`/`bomb contact.

You mention contacts being detected in multiple threads - I can't remember reading this anywhere, but I don't think that having multiple threads controlling a SpriteKit scene is a good idea, if it's even possible.